# rails3-jquery-autocomplete: Javascript TypeError

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-autocomplete

Rails 3.2.11

I followed the instructions for this gem: https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete. When I load the page that I want to have the autocompleted field, Jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete-rails.js, etc are all being loaded. However, upon loading the page, I get this in the error console:

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'this.live')

The I uncompress the js file, and this is the function being referred to:

```
(function(jQuery)
{
  var self = null;
  jQuery.fn.railsAutocomplete = function() {
    return this.live('focus',function() {
      if (!this.railsAutoCompleter) {
        this.railsAutoCompleter = new jQuery.railsAutocomplete(this);
      }
    });
  };
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on? Since I'm not using '$' anywhere, the noConflict option doesn't seem to matter, and either way doesn't fix the issue. I didn't make any changes to autocomplete-rails.js

What's weird is that I swear this was working at some point, but I can't for the life of me figure out what changed to break it.

Comment: Yup, turns out I had an errant javascript_include_tag that loaded another copy of jquery. That was the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, turns out I had an errant javascript_include_tag that loaded another copy of jquery. That was the issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe the original poster's own answer was part of the solution for me as well.  Using rails 3.2.13, jquery 1.9.0 and jquery-ui 1.9.2.  More completely I also:

- upgraded rails3-jquery-autocomplete to latest (from 1.0.9 to 1.0.11, when I saw: "When possible, use jQuery .on() rather than .live()" in the Changelog in [rails3-jquery-autocomplete at github](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)
- removed possibly redundant or conflicting jquery includes
- reordered includes, specifically placing underscore.js after autocomplete-rails
- full stop and clearing of caches and compiled assets

After the first 3 steps, the broken behavior was still there (after each step I restarted server only).  The last step was out of laziness, but thankfully showed that the combination of the above worked.